# Where's the Best place to start a lyrics website?

Tags: web

I'm making an attempt to recover the lyrics of my local folk songs and create a website. I would like to have sorting options like A-Z links, by artist etc. Could not find any good answer on Google. Can anyone share where's the good start for this kind of project? would CMS like drupal or wordpress  be useful tool? Are there any readymade plugins or extension available? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are WordPress themes custom designed for a lyrics site.  Here is an excellent example on ThemeForest.
[Muusico](http://themeforest.net/item/muusico-song-lyrics-wordpress-theme/10964140)

If you aren't a web designer, WordPress is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I am not a website developer. So muusico looks good. But wamted to try an alternative too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Here is a link to a detailed post for using WordPress as a lyrics site *without* buying a theme.  It is very detailed.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-bublish-lyrics-using-wordpress